# Can I return fields as nested objects on Sequelize js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following query in **sequelize.js**:

```
getBookingById: (req, res) => {
  models.booking.findAll({
    where: { 
      id: { $in: [1, 2, 3] },
    },
    include: [{ 
      model: models.cust,
      attributes: ['name', 'id'],
    }],
    attributes: [['id', 'bookingId'], 'propertyKey', 'propertyId'] })
  .then((result) => {
    if (!result) return res.status(204);

    return res.status(200).json(result);
  }).catch(err => res.status(500);
};
```

My response is as following:

```
[{
   "bookingId": 1,
   "propertyKey": "ABC",
   "propertyId": "123",
   "cust": {
      "name": "David David",
      "id": 8
   }
},

{
   "bookingId": 2,
   "propertyKey": "ABC",
   "propertyId": "123",
   "cust": {
      "name": "David David",
      "id": 8
   }
}]
```

I want to return `propertyKey` and `propertyId` fields as a nested object as:

```
"property": {
   "propertyKey": "ABC",
   "propertyId": "123",
}
```

Is it possible to do it within sequelize query or, should I parse the result after?

Answer (score 0):

You can change `result` variable before returning.

```
  .then((result) => {
    if (!result) return res.status(204);
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length ; i++){
       result[i].property = {
                        "propertyKey" : result.propertyKey ,
                        "propertyId": result.propertyId
                      }
        delete result[i].propertyKey; 
        delete result[i].propertyId;
    }
    return res.status(200).json(result);
  }).catch(err => res.status(500);
```

Comment: you need the iterate the array of objects. question updated.